# One $this assignment between event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a little piece of code:

```
if (PZ_APP.dom.isAnyDomElement($textInputs)){
    $textInputs.on("focus", function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            placeholder = $this.attr('data-placeholder') || "Wpisz tekst...";
        if ($this.val() === placeholder){
            $this.val("");
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            placeholder = $this.attr('data-placeholder');
        if ($this.val() === ""){
            $this.val(placeholder);
        }
    });
```

Can I avoid multiple var $this = $(this) assignments between event handlers?

Answer (score 1):

Given that `$textInputs` appears to match multiple elements, and you need `this` to be the element on which the event actually fired:

No. `this` only gets the right value inside each of the functions.

Comment: Maybe can I write .on("focus blur") then check  event type inside event handler? But i dont know its better way to write this...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for optimization purposes (only compute once), as per @Quentin's answer, then no. But if you want to do it for stylistic purposes, you can, but its not really any better...

```
  function aopPreface(fn) {
    return function() {
      fn.call(this, $(this));
    };
  };

  if (PZ_APP.dom.isAnyDomElement($textInputs)){
    $textInputs.on("focus", aopPreface(function($this){
      var placeholder = $this.attr('data-placeholder') || "Wpisz tekst...";
      if ($this.val() === placeholder){
        $this.val("");
      }
    })).blur(aopPreface(function($this){
      var placeholder = $this.attr('data-placeholder');
      if ($this.val() === ""){
        $this.val(placeholder);
      }
    }));
  }
```

I am not advocating for this in this situation because IMO it is not really any cleaner or clearer or faster, but if you do end up doing a lot of the same things before or after a set of function calls, the pattern is a pretty useful refactoring tool. (In your case, the placeholder variable might be movable as well.

Comment: When i have more assignments like this( like 10 or 20) using this pattern speed up my code, or it is just for styling purposes?

Comment: This is *not* an optimization, it is only a DRY refactoring. The $this will be recomputed every time. However, computing $this on event handlers is not exactly a expensive operation, so not generally something that is worrisome if that helps any.